# bndtools : How to get latest version for a jar file or a plugin

Tags: ant, osgi, osgi-bundle, bndtools

I am new in bndtools. I am wondering if there is any way to retrieve the latest version of my jar file? My lib folder has a lot of JARs version (My-Api-1.0.50, My-Api-1.0.85, My-Api-1.0.90)?

I managed to resolve dependencies by using ant. My JARs files are saved in lib folder. I want to use it in my bnb.bnb. But I need to use the latest version.

instead of :

```
-buildpath:     lib/My-Api-1.0.90.jar;version=file
```

I want something like that or an alternative solution :

```
-buildpath:     lib/My-Api-[**latestVertion**].jar;version=file
```

Please advise?? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mangaed to solve this problem by:

- Add Install Ivy Plugin Automatically by using Ivy only in your ant build scripts http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.2.0/install.html
- Rename the Jar retrived (MyApi-latest.jar)

> ```
> <move tofile="lib/MyApi-latest.jar" force="true">
>     <fileset dir="lib">
>         <include name="My-Api*.jar" />
>         <exclude name="My-Api-latest.jar"/>
>     </fileset>
> </move>
> ```

- In my bnd.bnd

-buildpath: lib/My-Api-latest.jar;version=file